# How to get connection from node-data to master in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, devops, elastic-stack, devops-services

I checked all documentations in internet by googling. I tried to bind node-data and master node. But I realized that there is an error in my logs;

Eror: if I check "192.168.5.84" logs; below error occurs.

[node1] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1])

```js
2017-08-16 13:37:38 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
[2017-08-16T13:37:43,253][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node1] initializing ...
[2017-08-16T13:37:43,346][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [node1] using [1] data paths, mounts [[(C:)]], net usable_space [10.7gb], net total_space [39.6gb], spins? [unknown], types [NTFS]
[2017-08-16T13:37:43,346][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [node1] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2017-08-16T13:37:43,472][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node1] node name [node1], node ID [81pArkMqSUuBVnKwny1Blw]
[2017-08-16T13:37:43,472][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node1] version[5.4.1], pid[7632], build[2cfe0df/2017-05-29T16:05:51.443Z], OS[Windows Server 2012 R2/6.3/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_131/25.131-b11]
[2017-08-16T13:37:43,472][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node1] JVM arguments [-Xms2g, -Xmx2g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+DisableExplicitGC, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Delasticsearch, -Des.path.home=C:\elk\elasticsearch, -Des.default.path.logs=C:\elk\elasticsearch\logs, -Des.default.path.data=C:\elk\elasticsearch\data, -Des.default.path.conf=C:\elk\elasticsearch\config, exit, -Xms2048m, -Xmx2048m, -Xss1024k]
[2017-08-16T13:37:45,706][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node1] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2017-08-16T13:37:45,706][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node1] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2017-08-16T13:37:45,706][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node1] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2017-08-16T13:37:45,706][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node1] loaded module [lang-groovy]
[2017-08-16T13:37:45,706][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node1] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2017-08-16T13:37:45,706][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node1] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2017-08-16T13:37:45,706][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node1] loaded module [percolator]
[2017-08-16T13:37:45,706][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node1] loaded module [reindex]
[2017-08-16T13:37:45,706][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node1] loaded module [transport-netty3]
[2017-08-16T13:37:45,706][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node1] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2017-08-16T13:37:45,706][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node1] no plugins loaded
[2017-08-16T13:37:50,987][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [node1] using discovery type [zen]
[2017-08-16T13:37:52,347][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node1] initialized
[2017-08-16T13:37:52,347][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node1] starting ...
[2017-08-16T13:37:53,190][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [node1] publish_address {192.168.5.84:9300}, bound_addresses {192.168.5.84:9300}
[2017-08-16T13:37:53,206][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [node1] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks
[2017-08-16T13:37:56,362][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [node1] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
[2017-08-16T13:37:59,378][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [node1] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
[2017-08-16T13:38:02,394][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [node1] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [1]), pinging again
```

My Master : (it is working perfect!) 10.180.11.82

```js
cluster.name: elasticsearch         
node.name: "lmaster"             
node.master: true              
node.data: true


network.host: 10.180.11.82
http.port: 333
#network.bind_host: ["192.168.5.84"]
#discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: true
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.180.11.82:333"]
```

My data Node : (Above error occurs here) 192.168.5.84

```js
network.host: 192.168.5.84
http.port: 333
cluster.name: elasticsearch    
node.name: "node1"  
node.master: false
node.data: true               
                        
#discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.180.11.82:333"]   
#network.bind_host: 10.180.11.82
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.180.11.82:333"]
```

Comment: Why do you need port 333 specifically? I think that, even in Windows, ports 0-1024 are kind of "reserved"/special.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your settings are all over the place. Start with something simpler, like the following, make sure it works and then, if not happy with what ports/IPs are used, start changing:

Node `10.180.11.82`:

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch         
node.name: "lmaster"             
node.master: true              
node.data: true

network.host: 10.180.11.82
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["192.168.5.84:9300"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

Node `192.168.5.84`:

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch    
node.name: "node1"  
node.master: false
node.data: true               

network.host: 192.168.5.84
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.180.11.82:9300"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

Comment: i am geeting this error [node-2] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [2]), pinging again

Comment: You did something wrong. For one, the error says `but needed [2]` and in my suggested configuration I mentioned `minimum_master_nodes: 1` not 2. Post the configuration you used.

Comment: @ArgusMalware any progress on this?

Comment: node.name: node-1
node.master: true
node.data: true
network.host: 172.31.24.193
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["172.31.24.193","172.31.25.87","172.31.23.237"]
discovery.zen.hosts_provider: ec2
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2

Comment: node.name: node-2
node.master: true
node.data: true
network.host: 172.31.23.237
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["172.31.24.193","172.31.25.87","172.31.23.237"]
discovery.zen.hosts_provider: ec2
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2

Comment: node.name: node-3
node.master: true
node.data: true
network.host: 172.31.25.87
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["172.31.24.193","172.31.25.87","172.31.23.237"]
discovery.zen.hosts_provider: ec2
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2

Comment: these are the three nodes configuration above ,besides i have installed discovery-ec2 plugin and i have put the aws instance access key and secret key using that...

Comment: i am getting error for each node like this  [node-3] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[Candidate{node={node-3}{FDEsu7GNR4Cdmo0Isca4Cw}{Zaj6cJgUSjim2zVOX_sUxA}{172.31.23.237}{172.31.23.237:9300}, clusterStateVersion=-1}]], but needed [2]), pinging again

Comment: That's a completely different issue. You are using EC2 plugin, which is different than what the original author of the post used. You should have posted a different question and offer a bounty on that one and not hijack this one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166730/discussion-between-argus-malware-and-andrei-stefan).